# Select all rows based on alternative publisher

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I want list all the rows by alternative publisher with price ascending, see the example table below.

```
id publisher   price
1    ABC       100.00
2    ABC       150.00
3    ABC       105.00 
4    XYZ       135.00       
5    XYZ       110.00
6    PQR       105.00
7    PQR       125.00
```

The expected result would be:

```
id publisher   price
1    ABC       100.00
6    PQR       105.00
5    XYZ       110.00
3    ABC       105.00
7    PQR       125.00
4    XYZ       135.00       
2    ABC       150.00
```

What would be the required SQL?

Comment: Why does 115.00 belong to XYZ in the first row, and PQR in the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select id, publisher, price
from (
  select id, publisher, price,
         row_number() over (partition by publisher order by price) as rn
  from publisher
) t
order by rn, publisher, price
```

The window functions assigns unique numbers for each publisher price. Based on that the outer order by will then first display all rows with rn = 1 which are the rows for each publisher with the lowest price. The second row for each publisher has the second lowest price and so on.

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06ece/2

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, publisher, price
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY publisher ORDER BY price), publisher;
```

One cannot use the output of [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in the `WHERE` or `HAVING BY` clauses because window functions are applied *after* those. But one can use window functions in the `ORDER BY` clause.

[SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/affaf/1)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your table name is - I have called it publishertable. But the following will order the result by price in ascending order - which is the result you are looking for:

```
select id, publisher, price from publishertable order by price asc
```

Comment: i also need to sort alternatively based on the publisher

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: The query will return the results in the order you have specified in your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

if I've got it right. You should use [ROW_NUMBER() function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) to range prices inside of each publisher and then order by this range and publisher.

```
SELECT ID,
       Publisher,
       Price,
       Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Publisher ORDER BY Price) as rn
FROM T
ORDER BY RN,Publisher
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0ad68/3)</kbd>